# Select a option from a database based on different variables?

Tags: php, mysql, database, logic

I am looking to make PHP code that selects the best option in a data table. What is considered "best" would be based off of the variables/columns. I understand that I would need to start a mysqli query and create a couple of loops to search through the database, but I am not entirely sure how to implement something like this.

To give a more in-depth explanation of what I am talking about, here as an example.

(START EXAMPLE)

Lets say I have a database and there is a table with items in it. There are 3 columns: Item ID, Type, On Sale. I want to make it so that a user is able to pick out the best option based on those variables. In addition to finding the "best" option, it selects the one that is first listed in that order (in this case lowest Item ID).
Imagine this table:

```
Item ID | Type | On Sale
---------------------
1      | Chair | 0 
2      | Table | 1
3      | Chair | 1  
4      | Oven  | 0  
5      | Table | 1
6      | Oven  | 0
```

The level of important goes like Type>On Sale>Item ID (lowest).

A user is looking for a chair. Item 3 is selected because it is his item and it is the first one also on sale.

A user is looking for a table. Item 2 is selected over Item 5 because it is listed higher (or in this case, has a lower Item ID)

A user is looking for an oven. Item 4 is selected because no ovens are on sale. Because no options are on sale, it selects the lowest Item ID of the ovens listed.

(END EXAMPLE)

So how should I go about this? Any answers would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * from table_name where Type = type_specified_by_user order by On Sale, Item ID
```

Comment: I am assuming 'type_specified_by_user' would really be a variable like $usertype. So I would make something like `select * from table_name where Type = $usertype order by On Sale, Item ID`

Comment: where $usertype could be chair

Comment: Because I tried this and essentially what happens is that I get an error basically saying `Chair is not a column`. In this scenerio would type_specified_by_user have to be a column or a variable?

Comment: Specifically, `mysqli_sql_exception: Unknown column 'chair' in 'where clause' `

Comment: The variable needs to be in quotes. e.g. `Type = '" . $usertype . "'` although you would want to sanitize the user input (or ideally use parametrization) to prevent sql injection.